# Which value has $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] when IP is not sent in PHP?

Tags: php, ip-address

I've read that is is possible that a client doesn't send an IP-Address on requesting. So I would prevent that a user can access to my page without giving an IP-Address.
For the case the IP-Adress is not sent, which value has $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] (PHP)? May `null`, `""`, or `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: It is not possible to establish a TCP connection without showing IP addresses.

Comment: Where have you read that? The IP address exchange is part of the TCP/IP handshake. No TCP/IP, no HTTP request. No HTTP request, no PHP execution.

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is set by the server. The client cannot influence it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany If you run from cli then `REMOTE_ADDR` is not set

Comment: @DarkBee Then there's no "client" either, because there's also no "server".

Comment: @DarkBee while you are technically correct, your remark doesn't apply here because the OP asks about using the PHP on the webserver.

Comment: @deceze I've read that in an article about proxy-servers. After that I tested it using [http://ipv6-test.com](http://ipv6-test.com) and on both connection-types stand `not supported`

Comment: @deceze False. PHP scripts can be executed separately from an HTTP server. The `$_SERVER` superglobal then contains the environment variables of the process.

Comment: @Rhymoid That's about your server setup. *The client* will have to send their IP. If your server internally filters it out and doesn't pass it to PHP, that's a different problem. It would also affect all clients equally, and not some clients selectively.

Comment: If the client uses a proxy server, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains the IP address of the proxy server (or of the last proxy server when the request passed through more than one). Some web servers can be configured to extract the client's real IP address from the request headers (if it's present there) and put it in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but I wouldn't rely on this behaviour.

Comment: @HelloToYou On ipv6-test.com, neither IPv4 nor IPv6 are supported by your browser?! What kind of proxy setup are you testing there?

Comment: @deceze Don't know exactly, it's some days ago and the server was from a proxy-list. Now I'm developing using PHP and would like to prevent that a user can't access without an IP-Address.

Comment: That problem mostly solves itself. (Putting aside all the possible asterisks about server misconfiguration etc. where PHP will simply not be passed the address by the web server.) If you don't know the IP address of the client, you cannot send them any response to their HTTP request. The responds needs to be delivered to an IP, and if the server doesn't know which IP to deliver the response to, it can't send any. Hence IP exchange is guaranteed in the TCP/IP protocol.

Comment: @DarkBee If you run from client, there is no TCP connection.

Comment: @axiac you don't need a webserver filtering anything when you can see all the http headers with PHP itself `getallheaders();`

Answer (score 0):

There is always an IP, however when you have several layers of software the *original* IP can be lost on its way to PHP unless the software is configured correctly.

It's not uncommon to have a setup stack with Varnish > Nginx > PHP-FPM, where responds to the original request (and get the visitor IP) and then in turn contacts the web server (nginx) which in turn calls PHP-FPM. In all of these "forwards" each software must be configured to include the original IP in headers or otherwise.

This is what the HTTP headers `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` are used for.

(Nginx and other software has configuration directives and modules to help with the specific scenario I mentioned above.)